# Programmatically add UIPickerView and Fill its data from Sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView control to fill it from sqlite.

this is my singleSelectedData property on .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *singleSelectedData;
```

this is my ViewDidload method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


_singleSelectedData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


[self loadQuestions];
}
```

this is the loadQuestions method which i create uipickerview. Also it loads many controls. Here you see only picker view section:

```
else if (inputType==SingleSelectionQuestion)
    {
        pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,656,768,44)];
        pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
        [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
        NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(pickerCancel:)];
        [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

        UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
        [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDone:)];
        [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

        pickerToolbar.hidden=YES;
        myPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,700,768,260)];
        myPicker.tag = [[[dataQuestions objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"ids"] integerValue];
        myPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
        myPicker.dataSource = self;
        myPicker.delegate = self;
        myPicker.hidden = YES;
        [myPicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        myPicker.tag=[[[dataQuestions objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"ids"] integerValue];

        UIButton *buttonControl = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        buttonControl.tag = [[[dataQuestions objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"ids"] integerValue];
        [buttonControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"combobox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonControl setTitle:@"Seçiniz" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonControl setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buttonControl.frame = CGRectMake(30,sectionY + mainCategoryHeight+subCategoryHeight+questionLabel.frame.size.height +offsetQuestion,433,38);
        [buttonControl addTarget:self action:@selector(selectSingleChoice:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        NSMutableArray *choices=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[DBHelper getSharedInstance:[LoggedinUser sharedCenter].dbFileName] getQuestionChoicesByQuestionID:[[dataQuestions objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"ids"]]];
        _singleSelectedData= [choices valueForKey:@"choiceName"];
       // singleSelectedData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"aaa",@"vvv", nil];



        [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
        [self.scrlview addSubview:pickerToolbar];
        [self.scrlview addSubview:buttonControl];


    }
```

EDIT:

this is the method i select from sqlite:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) getQuestionChoicesByQuestionID:(NSString *)questionID
{
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select CHOICE_ID,QUESTION_ID,NAME FROM T_PROGRAM_QUESTION_CHOICE as p INNER JOIN T_QUESTION_OPTION_CHOICE as c on c.ID=p.CHOICE_ID WHERE QUESTION_ID=%@",questionID];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    NSMutableArray *questionIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *choiceIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *choiceNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement,nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {


        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            NSString *choiceID = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                              (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            [choiceIDs addObject:choiceID];


            NSString *questionID = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                             (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            [questionIDs addObject:questionID];

            NSString *choiceName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                   (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            [choiceNames addObject:choiceName];



        }

        sqlite3_reset(statement);
        if(questionIDs !=nil)
        {

            for (int index = 0; index<questionIDs.count; index++) {

                NSMutableDictionary *dataAddDic =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                [dataAddDic setValue:[choiceIDs objectAtIndex:index] forKeyPath:@"choiceID"];
                [dataAddDic setValue:[questionIDs objectAtIndex:index] forKeyPath:@"questionID"];
                [dataAddDic setValue:[choiceNames objectAtIndex:index] forKeyPath:@"choiceName"];

                [mainArray addObject:dataAddDic];
            }
            if(mainArray.count>0)
            {

                return mainArray;
            }
            else
            {

                return nil;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"problem1: %@",statement);
            return nil;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"problem2: %@",statement);
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"problem3");
}
return nil;
}
```

as you see i set singleSelectedData to an array. THE ARRAY is NOT NULL. But somehow my picker view has no items when the view loads. if i set singleSelectedData array with objects manually. The items show. I don't understand what is the difference and wondering how can i get items from sqlite and show it?

Comment: Remove `myPicker.hidden = YES;` and `[myPicker reloadAllComponents];` after getting array.

Comment: if your array is empty you should show us the source code for the getQuestionChoicesByQuestionID method.

Comment: .hidden is not the problem. when button touched i make it active. i also try reloadAllComponents but nothing changed. I also add my getQuestionChoicesByQuestionID method to my question.

Comment: It is very strange code
`_singleSelectedData = [choices valueForKey:@"choiseName"];`
`choices` is declared as an array but you try to get item as if it were dictionary.
Which is result type of `_singleSelectedData`?
And manually you fill up `singleSelectedData` without prefix `_`.

Comment: Well, after you post `getQuestionChoicesByQuestionID` it become more clear.
You should get your array with `singleSelectedData = [choices.firstObject valueForKey:@"choiceName"]`

Comment: when i write NSLog(@"%@",_singleSelectedData); at the end of viewDidLoad (just after loadQuestions) it comes empty. So i think the problem is about the singleSelectedData property i fill it but somehow it loses its data

Comment: check that `choiceNames` is correctly feed in your getQuestionChoicesByQuestionID method.

Comment: Btw you are not setting an array for a key value here: [dataAddDic setValue:[choiceNames objectAtIndex:index] forKeyPath:@"choiceName"];

Comment: @ercan Sometimes NSDictionary will return null if any of the value is null during set value in NSDictionary. I think in your case this will be the reason. Please check.

Comment: ok found the problem. it is silly mistake for me. my load questions has a for loop and there are lots of SingleSelectionQuestions so my array gets the last object of for loop and it is empty :(. Now i try to find how to get arrays one by one dynamically.